# How to check version of Spark and Hadoop in AWS glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am using AWS with (Basic support plan). I want to know which version of Spark and Hadoop (HDFS) is getting used in AWS glue jobs. So that I can setup the same environment in my local machine for development.

Or if i get to know version of Spark then corresponding which version of Hadoop is used by AWS glue jobs or vice-versa.

As I am using Basic Support plan. So, I can't raise case to support center.
Any idea where I can check in AWS glue jobs... Spark and Hadoop version?

Any kind of help and suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Spark > 2.0 then

**`1.In Pyspark:`**

***Get Spark version:***

```
print("Spark Version:" + spark.version)
```

In **spark < 2.0:**

```
sc.version
```

***Get Hadoop versio*n:**

```
print("Hadoop version: " + sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo.getVersion())
```

**`2.In Scala:`**

***Spark Version:***

```
println ("Spark Version:" + spark.version)
```

in **spark < 2.0:**

```
sc.version
```

***Hadoop version:***

```
println("Hadoop version: " + org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo.getVersion())
```

Comment: Excellent. This saved my life! So dramatic, `LoL` but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue supports Apache Spark 2.2.1 as documented [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/04/aws-glue-now-supports-apache-spark-221/)

AWS has not documented hadoop version for AWS Glue anywhere. However, the as AWS Glue is actually backed by AWS EMR, and the hadoop version will be 2.8.x.

As per following documentation or hadoop/spark on AWS EMR I assume it to be 2.8.3.

[AWS EMR hadoop release history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/Hadoop-release-history.html)

[AWS EMR spark release history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/Spark-release-history.html)

where the release label 5.12.2 has spark 2.2.1 and hadoop 2.8.3